# How to import prototype to Pascal

Tags: prototype, inno-setup, installshield

I do have a function prototype from InstallShield script, unfortunately I am unable to import it to Pascal Code

```
#define SERIAL_DLL "Serial.dll"
prototype cdecl NUMBER Serial._ValidateCDKey(
 HWND, 
 BYREF STRING, BYREF STRING, BYREF STRING, BYREF STRING, 
 BYREF STRING, BYREF STRING, BYREF STRING, BYREF STRING, 
 BYREF STRING, BYREF STRING, BYREF STRING, 
 BYREF NUMBER, BYREF NUMBER);      

prototype BOOL IsSerialCorrect( STRING );
```

I was able to import DLL successfully, but every attempt to call the function ends up with Access Violation.

Comment: Rather post prototypes for that library than their imports from InstallShield.

Comment: This is all I have :( I wanted to create the installer with Inno as I do not have InstallShield. This is the archive script that I have access to.

Comment: Do you know at least whether those strings are Unicode or ANSI ? Also, are you sure the second prototype uses `stdcall` instead of `cdecl` ?

Comment: `_` suggests it's an AnsiString, but that may be checked later. But I may be wrong...

Comment: OK, if it is undoable, than it may be Closed.

Comment: I haven't said that. You'll just have a series of parameters with unknown meaning (like `Param1: HWND; Param2: AnsiString` etc.). But sorry, I don't have extra time to study how InstallShield scripting works right now. So let's keep this opened for someone who knows.

Comment: OK, thanks for tips and information.

Comment: If you were "able to import DLL successfully" that implies that you have some Inno script that imports the DLL.  If you're trying to ask why this didn't work, why didn't you post that?

Comment: Without knowing more about the function's C-equivalent interface, this question will be impossible to answer. As Miral suggests, you may be able to extract this information from an existing script, but the best source is the original code for the DLL.